# Change the cell color depending on the date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to display two different colors in my table that is created date is equal or less than 3 days the cell should be "#FFFF00" color. otherwise the cell should be a "#008000", here is my code,

```
<?php if ($project->post_date) : ?>                                            
<?php
$today_time = strtotime(date('m/d/y'));
$created_time =  "<?php echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($project->post_date)-3) ?>";
if ($created_time == $today_time) {
$stylis = "style='color:#ffff00;'";
} else {
$stylis = "style='color:#008000'"; 
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Remove the `<?php ` tags from `$created_time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code will work for you:

```
if ($project->post_date) {
    $today_time = strtotime('-3 day');  
    $created_time = date('m/d/y', strtotime($project->post_date));
    echo $created_time. " - ".$today_time."<br>";
    if (strtotime($created_time) > $today_time) {
        $stylis = "style='color:#ffff00;'";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $stylis = "style='color:#008000'"; 
    }
}
```

Please let us know if you need any further help.

Thanks!

Comment: hope this will solve your issue. so you can give it upvote

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
<?php
  if($project->post_date){
    $today_time = date('m/d/y');// Change this
    $created_time =  date('m/d/y', strtotime($project->post_date .'-3 days'));
    if ($created_time == $today_time) $stylis = "style='color:#ffff00;'";
    else $stylis = "style='color:#008000'"; 
    echo $stylis;
}
?>
```

Comment: is this code correct? it won't land in else always? i didn't tested the code, but just asking.

Comment: Thanks Sharma,
I tried your solution,but it change all cell color to "#008000"

Comment: It is all based on your variable $project->post_date. It it will change Color will defiantly change.

Comment: I will explain exactly what i want,
assume, $created_time is (11/09/2017, 11/08/2017, 11/07/2017) in this case the cell will be highlighted "#FFFF00" this color. else the cell will be highlighted "#008000"